# How to handle RequestedClaimTypes in GetProfileDataAsync?

Tags: identityserver4

Writing my own IMPL of IProfileService for IdentityServer4

Trying to figure out how context.RequestedClaimTypes is intended to operate.

Does context.RequestedClaimTypes indicate additional claims to return (in addition to "SUB") or does context.RequestedClaimTypes indicate only return the requested  claims and no more?

Answer (score 1):

`RequestedClaimTypes` is the flattened list of the claim types that are associated with the scopes the client has requested.

That's what the client expects to get back - what you actually return, is up to you.